# Print min and max of a hash value in Perl with corresponding key

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, hash

I'm new to Perl (I would say to programming in general too) and I am trying to fix a simple issue with a perl script I am doing for a school assignment. I am not supposed to use any module, I don't think they would accept it because I must learn how to do things first.

I am asked to create an html input form to put students name and marks and pass them to my perl script and calculate each student GPA, and everything works fine until now.

Then I am supposed to save these information in an hash and get the student name of who got the highest GPA and then the student name who got the lowest, but nothing is working.

First of all I defined each GPA outside any function, to be readable my every subroutine, and then I tried to assign each student name his GPA, but I am not sure it's correct the way I did.

```
my $cgi = CGI -> new();

my @name = $cgi->param('name');

my $gpa_one;
my $gpa_two;
my $gpa_three;
my $gpa_four;
my $gpa_five;
my $gpa_six;
my $gpa_seven;
my $gpa_eight;
my $gpa_nine;
my $gpa_ten;

my %stud_gpa = (
$name[0] => $gpa_one,
$name[1] => $gpa_two,
$name[2] => $gpa_three,
$name[3] => $gpa_four,
$name[4] => $gpa_five,
$name[5] => $gpa_six,
$name[6] => $gpa_seven,
$name[7] => $gpa_eight,
$name[8] => $gpa_nine,
$name[9] => $gpa_ten,
);
```

Each GPA is the result of a subroutine.

I have been trying to sort the GPAs in multiple ways (sorting the hash, just trying to assign each of them to a simple array and to sort the array) but there's no way for me to let it work.

this is the subroutine that I tried to do with the hash:

```
sub gpa_hash{

    my @gpavalues = sort { $stud_gpa{$a} <=> $stud_gpa{$b} } keys %stud_gpa;
    my $highest = $gpavalues[-1];
    my $smallest = $gpavalues[0];
    print "the max GPA is $highest of the student $stud_gpa{$gpavalues[-1]}<br>";
    print "the min GPA is $smallest of the student $stud_gpa{$gpavalues[0]}<br>";

}
```

But I get some problems with the output, because this is what I get:

```
the max GPA is of the student 
the min GPA is of the student
```

So then I tried just with an array, to see if it was maybe simpler to understand:

```
my @tot_gpa = (
           \$gpa_one,
           \$gpa_two,
           \$gpa_three,
           \$gpa_four,
           \$gpa_five,
           \$gpa_six,
           \$gpa_seven,
           \$gpa_eight,
           \$gpa_nine,
           \$gpa_ten
);

sub gpa{
    my $max = (sort { $a <=> $b } @tot_gpa)[-1];
    my $min = (sort { $a <=> $b } @tot_gpa)[0];
    print "this is the smallest GPA: $min<br>";
    print "this is the highest GPA: $max<br>";
}
```

But this is what I am getting:

```
this is the smallest GPA: SCALAR(0x8bcab0)
this is the highest GPA: SCALAR(0x8bcbd0)
```

I am sure I am doing something wrong first of all in assigning the variables to the array, because if I just print the array itself it gives me back this output:

```
SCALAR(0x8bcab0)
SCALAR(0x8bcad0)
SCALAR(0x8bcaf0)
SCALAR(0x8bcb10)
SCALAR(0x8bcb30)
SCALAR(0x8bcb50)
SCALAR(0x8bcb70)
SCALAR(0x8bcb90)
SCALAR(0x8bcbb0)
SCALAR(0x8bcbd0)
```

while if I just print the GPA variables alone I get the right corresponding number, like this `print "$gpa_one<br>";` gives me (as example) `2.1`. Can someone helps me understanding how to fix it? I'm going crazy...

Thank you!

Comment: Yes I’m using `use warnings;` and `use strict;` as well, but it doesn’t give me any error maybe because the syntax seems correct.. I just used `$gpa_one` and all the other values inside their own subroutines to give them the result, like this `$gpa_one = $sum/$average` So if I print only `$gpa_one` It works and it gives me the right gpa of the marks I put into the form, but the problem is when I pass it inside an array or an hash

Comment: Your statement `my @name = $cgi->param('name')` puts the `name` string into `$name[0]`. The remaining elements, `$name[1]` onwards, remain undefined, and you probably get warnings about *Use of uninitialized value*.

Answer (score 2):

The [sort](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) returns its *input list* sorted, so in your sub

```
sub gpa_hash {

    my @gpavalues = sort { $stud_gpa{$a} <=> $stud_gpa{$b} } keys %stud_gpa;
    my $highest = $gpavalues[-1];
    my $smallest = $gpavalues[0];
    ...
}
```

the `@gpavalues` *are not values* but are the keys, sorted by the criterion in the block.

So you'd retrieve values by

```
my $largest  = $stud_gpa{$gpavalues[-1]};
my $smallest = $stud_gpa{$gpavalues[0]};
```

or

```
my ($largest, $smallest) = @stud_gpa{ @gpavalues[-1,0] };
```

by using array and hash [slices](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices)  .

A few general comments.

It appears that you make variables global so that subroutines can see them. This may seem to work but it will surely lead to trouble as programs get any more complicated. You should always write your subs to take data they need from the calling code via arguments.

I don't know the purpose of the manual listing of all `$gpa_N`, but they should clearly be (unnamed) elements of a multi-valued data type or variable, like an array.  Given that you then assign them to hash values you may well do that right as you obtain those values.

Answer (score -1):

```
SCALAR(0x8bcbd0)
```

indicates you are printing a reference on a scalar

You will have to unreference in order to print the scalar and not its adress

this will be done by replacing

```
my $max = (sort { $a <=> $b } @tot_gpa)[-1];
```

by

```
my $max = ${(sort { int($$a) <=> int($$b) } @tot_gpa)[-1]};
```

the `$` at the begining and before `$a` and `$b` unreference your scalar.
With only `$a` and `$b` you would sort the adresses, not the values

`int` force int context to compare numbers and not strings

you can also fill your array with variables and not references, doing something like

```
my ($gpa_one, $gpa_two, $gpa_three, $gpa_four) = (12.5,15.8,1,2.5);

my @tot_gpa = (
          $gpa_one, 
          $gpa_two, 
          $gpa_three, 
          $gpa_four
);

my $max = (sort { $a <=> $b } @tot_gpa)[-1];
print $max;
```

prints `15.8`

**now with your hash I tried:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($gpa_one, $gpa_two, $gpa_three, $gpa_four) = (12.5,15.8,1,2.5);

my %stud_gpa = (
'a' => $gpa_one,
'b' => $gpa_two,
'c' => $gpa_three,
'd' => $gpa_four,

);

sub gpa_hash{

    my @gpavalues = sort { $stud_gpa{$a} <=> $stud_gpa{$b} } keys %stud_gpa;
    my $highest = $gpavalues[-1];
    my $smallest = $gpavalues[0];
    print "the max GPA is $highest of the student $stud_gpa{$gpavalues[-1]}<br>";
    print "the min GPA is $smallest of the student $stud_gpa{$gpavalues[0]}<br>";

}

gpa_hash();
```

it prints `the max GPA is b of the student 15.8<br>the min GPA is c of the student 1`

so name and gpa are switched, that's because `$highest` and `$smallest` contain the name of the student as you made the sort on `keys %stud_gpa`

I can't reproduce your problem

the way it could produce what you describe is that your `$gpa` are references.
declare your hash as you already do and modify your `gpa_hash` as follow, this should work

```
sub gpa_hash{

    my @gpavalues = sort { ${$stud_gpa{$a}} <=> ${$stud_gpa{$b}} } keys %stud_gpa;
    my $highest = $gpavalues[-1];
    my $smallest = $gpavalues[0];
    print "the max GPA is ${$stud_gpa{$highest}} of the student $highest<br>";
    print "the min GPA is ${$stud_gpa{$smallest}} of the student $smallest <br>";

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I’ll try in this way now, what about the other parts of the code? Is it correct to assign the scalars in the way I did into hashes and arrays? Because it prints the reference instead of the corresponding value even when I just print each element of the array as I shown

Comment: yep, because you filled your array with references (the `\ ` before the variable).
Another solution would be to fill your array with variables itselves (by removing the `\ ` ), this way you have to let your code as it is now, like  `my $max = (sort { $a <=> $b } @tot_gpa)[-1];`

Comment: I tried both way and the first one you told works perfectly with the array now, while if I try to remove the `\ ` from the variables and use `my $max = (sort { $a <=> $b } @tot_gpa)[-1];` it gives me back again the references `SCALAR(0x8eefd0)`... but at least the first one works good! :) is there a way to unreference scalars in the hash?

Comment: @Mattia: Why are you using references in the first place. You don't do it in your first example, but in the second you are assigning references like `\$gpa_one` etc. to `@tot_gpa`.